# Getting ERROR 999999 when trying to use arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server()?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-online, error-999999

Here is my code

```
def upload(name, client, working_dir):
  arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
  arcpy.SignInToPortal('https://www.arcgis.com', username, password)
  outdir = working_dir + "\\PROJECTS\\" + name + "\\sd\\"
  aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(working_dir + "\\PROJECTS\\data_holder\\data_holder.aprx")
  m = aprx.listMaps()[0]
  print("Uploading data for " + name)
  lyrs = m.listLayers()
  arcpy.mp.CreateWebLayerSDDraft(lyrs, outdir + name + ".sddraft", name, "MY_HOSTED_SERVICES", "FEATURE_ACCESS", name, True, True, False, False, False, name, name, name, None, None )
  arcpy.StageService_server(outdir + name + ".sddraft", outdir + name + ".sd", 102)
  arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(outdir + name + ".sd", 'My Hosted Services')
```

This is the error I am getting. I have tried multiple different ways to put in parameters.

> Uploading data for test_project
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "main.py", line 304, in module
>
> upload(name, client, working_dir)
>
> File "main.py", line 242, in upload
>
> arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(outdir + name + ".sd", 'My Hosted Services')
>
> File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\server.py", line 954, in UploadServiceDefinition
>       raise e
>
> File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\server.py", line 951, in UploadServiceDefinition
>       retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.UploadServiceDefinition_server(*gp_fixargs((in_sd_file, in_server, in_service_name, in_cluster, in_folder_type, in_folder, in_startupType, in_override, in_my_contents, in_public, in_organization, in_groups), True)))
>
> File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line 506, in 
>       return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
>
> arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
>
> ERROR: code:400, Invalid URL, Invalid URL, Bad syntax in request.
>
> Failed to execute (UploadServiceDefinition).

Comment: thats not your portal URL

Comment: Hmm. What would it be then? It seems to be connecting to my account and upload a service definition that is unusable from the code above.

Comment: ERROR: code:400, Invalid URL, Invalid URL, Bad syntax in request.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was trying to upload an xy event layer. I changed my code to upload from a gdb.